# Update a List of objects by comparing with another list

Tags: list, groovy

I do have two different lists of same object , one is with sample data , one is with real data. Few fields in the real data are messed up, I need to update the few fields of real data list , by getting those values from sample data .

Both lists are of same object, both have same unique key .

```
List<pojo> real = [(code:60,active:Y,account:check),(code:61,active:Y,account:check),(code:62,active:Y,account:check)];

List<pojo> sample = [(code:60,active:Y,account:saving),(code:61,active:Y,account:check),(code:62,active:Y,account:saving)]
```

I have around 60 objects in each list , In the above one I need to update real where code is 60 and 62 - account from check to saving.

I am  using  java 1.8  &  groovy

thanks

Comment: And when trying to implement that functionaility you encountered what problems specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
class Pojo {
    def code
    def active
    def account

    String toString() {
        account
   }
}

List<Pojo> real = [new Pojo(code: 60, active: 'Y', account: 'check'), new Pojo(code: 61, active: 'Y', account: 'check'), new Pojo(code: 62, active: 'Y', account: 'check')]

List<Pojo> sample = [new Pojo(code: 60, active: 'Y', account: 'saving'), new Pojo(code: 61, active: 'Y', account: 'check'), new Pojo(code: 62, active: 'Y', account: 'saving')]

real.each { r ->
    def acc = sample.find{it.code == r.code}?.account

    if (acc != null) {
        r.account = acc
    }
}

println real // prints [saving, check, saving]
```

The above sample iterates with each over each pojo in real and searches the corresponding object (that with the same code) in the sample list. If the corresponding object is found, the value of account in the object of the real list is overwritten, otherwise it will be left as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that updates `real` data after comparing with `sample` data as requested by OP.

Note that the input is not valid, so made it valid by changing values inside list as map. i.e.,

changed from `(code:60,active:'Y',account:'check')`
to `[code:60,active:'Y',account:'check']`

```
def realData = [[code:60,active:'Y',account:'check'],[code:61,active:'Y',account:'check'],[code:62,active:'Y',account:'check']]  
def sampleData = [[code:60,active:'Y',account:'saving'],[code:61,active:'Y',account:'check'],[code:62,active:'Y',account:'saving']]
realData.collect{rd -> sampleData.find{ it.code == rd.code && (it.account == rd.account ?: (rd.account = it.account))}}
println realData
```

**Output:**

```
[[code:60, active:Y, account:saving], [code:61, active:Y, account:check], [code:62, active:Y, account:saving]]
```

You can quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5198118991691776)</kbd>